# Good literature on unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Where can I find good literature on unit testing?  Book titles and links are welcome.

Update: 
Here is a list of books mentioned in answers below

[xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131495054)

[Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/)

[The Art Of Unit Testing](http://www.artofunittesting.com/)

The real challenge of software testing is solving the puzzle of test design.

Testing Object-Oriented Systems: Models, Patterns, and Tools provides three dozen test design patterns applicable to unit test design. It also provides many design patterns for test automation. These patterns distill many hard-won best practices and research insights.

[Pragmatic Unit Testing](https://pragprog.com/titles/utj/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-java-with-junit)

[Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321146530)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054)

Comment: +1 this is the only book I've ever bought on unit testing, and the only one that actually taught me something useful even just flipping through it.  Not necessarily a good book for beginners, as it has a lot of focus on the whys, not just the hows.

Answer (score 9):

[The Art Of Unit Testing](http://www.artofunittesting.com)

Answer (score 7):

[Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The real challenge of software testing is solving the puzzle of test design.

*Testing Object-Oriented Systems: Models, Patterns, and Tools* provides three dozen test design patterns applicable to unit test design. It also provides many design patterns for test automation.  These patterns distill many hard-won best practices and research insights.

The book is designed as a desk reference, so once you've determined which patterns fit your app, you only need to read about them. Because of this, it is a big book (1024 pages). I know, because I am the author.

Overview, reviews, and link to Amazon:
http://www.robertvbinder.com/home/thought-leadership/books/

Answer (score 2):

[Pragmatic Unit Testing](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/utj/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-java-with-junit) is a decent introduction to the why and some of the how.  I read the Java one even as I was primarily interested in C++, and the lessons still came through quite clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The [Unit testing videos](http://www.eventhelix.com/agile/unit-testing.htm) describe how to make your code testable.

Answer (score 1):

[Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)

[The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)

Answer (score 1):

I have only read the Art of Unit Testing by Roy Osherove, and it was quite revealing for me, despite not working with .NET technology myself. The examples are easy to understand by any programmer, the more difficult part being to identify the most suitable Unit Testing framework for your specific language / framework.

If you are curious, check the short notes I took (displayed in reverse chronological order):
http://myevernote.blogspot.com/search/label/The%20Art%20of%20Unit%20Testing%20%28Roy%20Osherove%29

A friend of mine, who did a lot more Unit Testing than I, said that the good practices were new for him also.