# How to know if there is a exception throw of an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, try-catch, log4net

Hi we are developping a application where we need to do multiple task in a row and those can take very long. So we create a class where it's a "runner" where I send a list of task he need to do and he do it all until it's finish. So if there is some exception while he run all task, he just throw it to log4net so we can debug all task that failed in one time. So I am unexperiment with unit testing and I try to use it now. My task is multiple file read. I send many file with different context so if I change something and it's not working, it will be my fault. But how do I know if I get a exception if I handle it with my log4net? How should I do otherwise to make it happen?

```
class Runner{
void addTask(...);
void execute(){
  foreach(var task in ListOfTask){
    try
    { DoSomeThing(); }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { Log.Error("Message", ex); }
  }
}

class XMLReader{
string Read();
}

[TestClass]
class Test{

  [TestMethod]
  [DeploymentItem("filePath1")]
  [DeploymentItem("filePath2")]
  [DeploymentItem("filePath3")]
  void TestRunner(){
    Runner r = new Runner();
    r.addTask("filePath1");
    r.addTask("filePath2");
    r.addTask("filePath3");
    r.execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look much like a unit test.  This looks like an *end to end execution of the application* wrapped in a method.  I recommend you read up a bit on unit testing.  (There's a closed but still useful Stack Overflow question on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923471/good-literature-on-unit-testing)  Your unit tests should invoke *specific* units of functionality, mocking any dependencies used by those units, and internally validating the results of those units.  Not simply running the entire application from a unit test method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't this way because you're only logging the exception. You should return some kind of result ("ListOfResult" perhaps, if it's ok if one task fails but you want the rest of the tasks to continue), or throw an exception if any failure should stop the process.